# Problem with query using Join if value of Join contains '

Tags: join, google-sheets, formula

I needed to find how to extract all lines from another sheet (Incidents!A2:P) to my sheet if line contains a list of words (B2:B) in column E.

I didn't want to ask everything from you so I had a look by myself and I succeed to write the following formula :

```
=query(Incidents!A2:P;"Select * where E matches " & "'" & (join("|";B2:B)) & "'")
```

It works perfectly fine ... except if one of the words of my list contains the ' character.

Example :

```
A     B

2   let go

3   let's go

4   lets go
```

My formula works if there's no " ' " in the line #3

I thing the "'" is understood as a programming symbol. Do someone have a solution ? An idea ?
Thanks

Oliver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing single quotes with doubled double quotes:

```
=query(Incidents!A2:P;"Select * where E matches " & """" & (join("|";B2:B)) & """")
```